# Slim Framework: как подключать

Tags: фреймворк, php, framework

Доброго времени суток! Ребята, кто работал с данным фреймворком? Я первый раз столкнулась с этим в принципе. У меня в задании условие: "web-cервер реализовать на `Slim` (фреймворк `php`)
 Запросы передавать js`введите код здесь`on-ом". Может кто подскажет ссылку на понятный источник, где описано, с чего начать работу с ним или может кто подсказать, с чего начинается работа, подключать его нужно ли и если да,то как. Спасибо

Comment: вот [русская дока по slim](http://slimframework.ru) перевод можно дополнять

Answer (score 5):

Начнем с того, что реализовать web-cервер на Slim не получиться - для работы этого фреймворка необходим web-server (Apache или NginX). 
Будем считать, что в задании условие «реализовать серверную часть на Slim»
Тогда, чтобы подключить данный фреймворк и начать с ним работать, неодбходимо, в самом минимальном случае:

1. Скачать последний [стабильный релиз фреймворка](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/zipball/master)
2. Распаковать архив с фреймворком в корневую директорию Вашего проекта
3. Отредактировать файл index.php:

   `<?php
   require 'Slim/Slim.php';
   \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
   $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
       echo "Hello, $name";
   });
   $app->run();`

Этого достаточно, чтобы подключить Slim фреймворк к проекту.
Чтобы проверить работу фреймворка, перейдите по адресу вашего проекта и добавтье в конце `hello/world` (`http://localhost/your-project-url/hello/world`). Если Вы увидете на экарне сообщение «Hello, world» - значит все работает!

Если же Вы знакомы с такой утилитой для работы с зависимостями, как Composer, то установить Slim еще проще. Об этом написано в офийиальной

Что Вам может понадобиться при работе со Slim:

1. [Документация по фреймворку](http://docs.slimframework.com/)
2. [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEA0VWHCFac) и [слайды](http://www.slideshare.net/jeremykendall/keeping-it-small-slim-php) доклада о том, как разрабатывать с использованием Slim
3. Хороший [туториал](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/rapid-application-prototyping-in-php-using-a-micro-framework/) про то, как работать со Slim

Comment: krlv, низкий Вам поклон, хоть какой-то луч света появился! Но что-то не очень у меня с миром здоровается. У меня на компе апачи стоит. Делала все по Вашим инструкциям, но когда добавляю в ад.строке /hello/world (т.е http://localhost/alex/form.php/hello/world),то ничего не происходит. Там страница авторизации находится,вот она и появляется. Что я могу не так делать?
P/S А в задании именно было написано "web-cервер реализовать на Slim(фреймворк php) Запросы передавать json-ом". Слово в слово.

Comment: Маргарита, как я понял http://localhost/alex/ адрес Вашего проекта. Тогда Вам надо внести некоторые изменения в файл .htaccess, в корневой директории проекта (этот файл был в архиве Slim фреймворка):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /alex/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

И убедитесь, что модуль mod_rewrite для Apache включен
Проверять работу фреймворка, в Вашем случае, стоит по адресу http://localhost/alex/hello/world

Comment: Не хватает кармы "добавить" к комментарию Krlv, поэтому пишу отдельно...
Строка http://localhost/your-project-url/hello/world должна бы содержать название файла: http://localhost/your-project-url/index.php/hello/xYzT
(тут написал xYzT т.к. в конце м.б. любэ)